# Excluir última vírgula de uma string

Tags: php

Tenho uma string:
`"imagens":["upload/7057c705298193c513f07fbb8fbe2856.jpg", "upload/30c2dbcd5c890e763fab6ccfa63ab24c.jpg", "upload/40f4af351cfa1d01ca2e468965d28626.jpg", ]`

E quero excluir a última vírgula dela, deixando ficar assim:
`"imagens":["upload/7057c705298193c513f07fbb8fbe2856.jpg", "upload/30c2dbcd5c890e763fab6ccfa63ab24c.jpg", "upload/40f4af351cfa1d01ca2e468965d28626.jpg"]`

Como fazer?

Comment: Provavelmente isso é um problema na geração da string, melhor do que tirar a vírgula é nem colocá-la. Mas pra ter certeza mesmo, somente vendo o código que gera a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Remove os dois últimos caracteres
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str)-2);

// Acrescenta de volta o ]
$str .= ']';
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso com a função `str_replace`

```
$string = '"imagens":["upload/7057c705298193c513f07fbb8fbe2856.jpg", "upload/30c2dbcd5c890e763fab6ccfa63ab24c.jpg", "upload/40f4af351cfa1d01ca2e468965d28626.jpg", ]';

echo str_replace(', ]', ']', $string);
```

O resultado será:

`"imagens":["upload/7057c705298193c513f07fbb8fbe2856.jpg", "upload/30c2dbcd5c890e763fab6ccfa63ab24c.jpg", "upload/40f4af351cfa1d01ca2e468965d28626.jpg"]`

Answer (score 0):

Veja o seguinte Trecho de código que remove a vírgula com ou sem espaço antes do colchete.

```
<?php
/*A string que vc forneceu*/
$texto = '"imagens":["upload/7057c705298193c513f07fbb8fbe2856.jpg", "upload/30c2dbcd5c890e763fab6ccfa63ab24c.jpg", "upload/40f4af351cfa1d01ca2e468965d28626.jpg", ]';

/*Limpa String*/
echo preg_replace("/,(\s{1,}|)]/", "]", $texto);
?>
```